# Difference in regex behavior between Perl and Python?

Tags: python, regex, perl

I have a couple email addresses, `'support@company.com'` and `'1234567@tickets.company.com'`.

In perl, I could take the `To:` line of a raw email and find either of the above addresses with

```
/\w+@(tickets\.)?company\.com/i
```

In python, I simply wrote the above regex as`'\w+@(tickets\.)?company\.com'` expecting the same result. However, `support@company.com` isn't found at all and a findall on the second returns a list containing only `'tickets.'`. So clearly the `'(tickets\.)?'` is the problem area, but what exactly is the difference in regular expression rules between Perl and Python that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for `re.findall`:

> ```
> findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>     Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.
>
>     If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a
>     list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>     has more than one group.
>
>     Empty matches are included in the result.
> ```

Since `(tickets\.)` is a group, `findall` returns that instead of the whole match.  If you want the whole match, put a group around the whole pattern and/or use non-grouping matches, i.e.

```
r'(\w+@(tickets\.)?company\.com)'
r'\w+@(?:tickets\.)?company\.com'
```

Note that you'll have to pick out the first element of each tuple returned by `findall` in the first case.

Comment: Okay, but interestingly, not *obvious*.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is in your expectations of extracted values.  Try using this in your current Python code:

```
'(\w+@(?:tickets\.)?company\.com)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems jump out at me:

1. You need to use a raw string to avoid having to escape "`\`"
2. You need to escape "`.`"

So try:

```
r'\w+@(tickets\.)?company\.com'
```

EDIT

Sample output:

```
>>> import re
>>> exp = re.compile(r'\w+@(tickets\.)?company\.com')
>>> bool(exp.match("s@company.com"))
True
>>> bool(exp.match("1234567@tickets.company.com"))
True
```

Comment: #2 is just me being a newb at stackoverflow. Fixed the initial post. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a difference in the regexes, but there is a difference in what you are looking for.  Your regex is capturing only `"tickets."` if it exists in both regexes.  You probably want something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

regex = re.compile("(\w+@(?:tickets\.)?company\.com)");

a = [
    "foo@company.com", 
    "foo@tickets.company.com", 
    "foo@ticketsacompany.com",
    "foo@compant.org"
];

for string in a:
    print regex.findall(string)
```